# How to find the minimum number of vertices whose removal make the graph disjoint

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given a graph $G = (V,E)$.

Is there any algorithm which finds the minimum number of vertices to be removed from $G$ so that every vertex in the graph becomes disjoint, *i.e.*, every vertex is disconnected from every other vertex?

Comment: @Raphael , I tried Articulation point algorithm but it does not give fully disconnected graph.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is known as *[vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover)*.  The minimum vertex cover of a graph is the smallest number of vertices adjacent to every edge.  The complement of a vertex cover is an *independent set*.

Given a graph $G = (V,E)$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the problem of finding whether $G$ has a vertex cover of size at most $k$ is NP-complete.  However, it admits a polynomial kernel and is thus *fixed-parameter tractable*.  It also admits a quite easy and nice $2^k n^{O(1)}$ branching algorithm:

Pick any edge $e = vu$:  Either $v$ goes to the vertex cover, or $u$ goes to the vertex cover.  Make a recursive algorithm which picks $e$, removes $v$ from the graph and calls itself recursively with $k-1$ as parameter.  If that fails, proceed by removing $u$.  If that fails as well, can conclude that there is no such vertex cover.

There are also nice 2-approximation algorithms for this problem.

Ps.  this is maybe one of the "easier" NP-hard problems.  So if you want to implement it, you're in good luck despite the hardness.

Pps.  if you want to find an [independent set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29) (also known as *stable set*) of size at least $k$, you are *out of luck*, as that problem is $W[1]$-complete, see the [W-hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity#W_hierarchy).  However, there is an $O(2^{0.288n})$ exact algorithm solving independent set using Measure and Conquer by Fomin et al. [(SODA 2006)](http://www.idsia.ch/~grandoni/Pubblicazioni/FGK06soda.pdf) ([doi=10.1.1.79.831](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.79.831)).  A quick caveat here:  Many are confused upon first reading why a trivial reduction does not show that independent set is in FPT as well.  The answer here lies in the fact that a reduction will set the new parameter $k' = O(n-k)$, i.e., the new parameter will depend on $n$ as well.

Comment: Also knowing something about the structure of the input graph might make the problem tractable. For example, the vertex cover problem is easy for trees.

Comment: Yes, and more generally it is solvable in linear time for chordal graphs. It also has a PTAS on planar graphs. That vertex cover is solvable in polytime on chordal graphs means that independent set is as well.

Comment: Just as a side note, is also $O(2^{\sqrt k}\cdot n^{O(1)})$ time solvable in graphs of H-Minor free for some fixed graph H. (which contains all of bounded genus and planar, ...) and the algorithm is actually easy (bidimentionality theory).

Comment: I'm not sure I would call any algorithm relying on the graph minors theorem "actually easy".  It's nothing you simply go ahead and implement. :)